# NFCTagReaderSession do not start reader session IOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, ios13

In my project I need to read NFC tag's serial number. According to apple developer site it is possible in iOS 13 using NFCTagReaderSession. Here is my code for setting up NFC Tag :

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
var readerSession1: NFCTagReaderSession?
////////
//inside view will appear
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                guard NFCTagReaderSession.readingAvailable else{
                    print("no nfc reading available")
                    showAlert(AlertTitle: MAppName, AlertMessage: NSLocalizedString("Your device is not compatible with NFC", comment: ""))
                    return
                }

                readerSession1 = NFCTagReaderSession.init(pollingOption: [.iso14443, .iso15693, .iso18092], delegate: self)
                // NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443, .iso15693, .iso18092], delegate: self,queue: nil)
            readerSession1?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near an NFC fish tag."
            readerSession1?.begin()
            } else {
            print("should do some fallback code")
            }

///// delegate methods
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension myVC: NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate{
    func tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession) {

    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {

    }

    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        print("\(tags.count) new RFID-Tags detected:")
                let rfidTagObj = tags.first as! NFCISO15693Tag
                for tag in tags {
                    let rfidTag = tag as! NFCISO15693Tag
                    print("- Is available: \(rfidTag.isAvailable)")
                    print("- Type: \(rfidTag.type)")
                    print("- IC Manufacturer Code: \(rfidTag.icManufacturerCode)")
                    print("- IC Serial Number: \(rfidTag.icSerialNumber)")
                    print("- Identifier: \(rfidTag.identifier)")
                }
    }

    func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCReaderSession) {

    }

    func readerSession(_ session: NFCReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
    }

    func readerSession(_ session: NFCReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {

    }

}
```

Well, the problem is my device (iPhone XR iOS 13.1.3) do not read any of tag. No error is displayed in code. The tag reader session do not display any kind of nfc reading popover as it supposed to show, No delegate method is triggered. 
Any reply would be appreciated. Using Xcode 11

Comment: You don't have any result because, I guess, you didn't prepare all settings for you app with NFC. Quite a lot of settings need to be done to run on a real device. More about configure the App to Detect NFC Tags - [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app). I've checked your code with my paid Apple developer account and it works correctly

Comment: thanks Vadim for testing my code!! can you tell me what according to you is missing in my project setting??

Comment: as I wrote you should add entitlements + info to plist file + set you capabilities with your Apple developer account - [Configure the App to Detect NFC Tags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app)